# Is there any place for DBN / Wake-Sleep / Up-Down / Pretraining in modern ML?

Tags: machine-learning, pre-training

I've been looking at DBNs:

- first a greedy (unsupervised) layerwise pretraining.
- now split weights into recognition R and generative G, and apply Wake-Sleep (again unsupervised, i.e. Unlabelled Data)
- now use back propagation with labelled data for fine tuning.

This approach looks aesthetically very attractive to me.

But I have heard that *"According to the keynote i saw from Bengio in december (2016), ReLU units solved the problem of deep nets; rendering pretraining largely obsolete."*

Are these pretty techniques set to be consigned to a chapter in the history books of ML?  Or are they still relevant?

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261751/why-are-deep-belief-networks-dbn-rarely-used/267282#267282 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163600/pre-training-in-deep-convolutional-neural-network/163805#163805